# How can I open a .mediawiki file in Word so that Word will interpret it as a MediaWiki file rather than a TXT file?

Tags: ms-word, mediawiki

I've recently installed the Microsoft Office Word Add-in For MediaWiki (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12298) and I'm able to save MediaWiki files just fine but I can't open them (they are opened as plain text).

How can I force MS Word to make the correct association for MediaWiki files?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. "Interpreting" the MediaWiki markup, i.e. wikitext, is called parsing. Writing a MediaWiki parser is a pain and there is no single parser which fully works yet, other than MediaWiki itself. LibreOffice's wiki-publisher plugin and those which copied it are able to produce good wikitext from their well-formed data format, but making this bidirectional is another matter.

Parsoid is almost perfect now and produces standard HTML, but it's a rather heavy application, you can't expect it to be embedded in Word. Maybe someone can write a LibreOffice plugin for Parsoid, though! Would be scary, but who knows.

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers for more information. Many tried and got hurt. :)